# how to separate the images in folder using image name python?

Tags: python

I need to separate the images in folder with it's filename in python.
for example, i have a folder of images named as, 
0_source.jpg, 0_main.jpg,0_cell.jpg, 1_net.jpg, 1_cells.jpg, 2_image.jpg,2_name.jpg

i want to separate these images and save in different folder like:
folder1:

0_source.jpg, 0_main.jpg, 0_cell.jpg

folder 2:

1_net.jpg, 1_cells.jpg

folder 3:

2_image.jpg, 2_name.jpg

I tried to look around, but seems none of them fits what i really needed.
hope someone here could help.
I'm open to any ideas, recommendation and suggestion, thank you.

Comment: `pathlib` in your hands

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to use a regular expression to extract the folder name starting from the image name. Then build the folders and move the images

```
import shutil
import re
import os

images = ["0_source.jpg", "0_main.jpg", "0_cell.jpg", "1_net.jpg", "1_cells.jpg", "2_image.jpg", "2_name.jpg"]

def build_images_folders(image_names: [str]):
    folder_name_regex = re.compile(r"^(\d)._*") # Regular expression which extract the folder starting from the image_name name

    for image_name in image_names:
        regex_match = folder_name_regex.match(image_name)
        if regex_match:
            folder_index = regex_match.group(1) # Extract the folder name
            folder_name = "{folder_prefix}{folder_index}".format(folder_prefix="folder_", folder_index=folder_index) # Build the folder name
            os.makedirs(folder_name, exist_ok=True) # Build the folder. If already exists, don't raise exception

            src_image_path = image_name
            dst_image_path = os.path.join(folder_name, image_name)
            shutil.move(src_image_path, dst_image_path)

        else:
            error = "Invalid image name format \"{image_name}\". Expecting <number>_<string>".format(image_name=image_name)
            raise ValueError(error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_images_folders(images
```